# how can i send push notification when browser is closed

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

I want to send a notification to PWA. I am working with service-worker and firebase.
It's only working whenever the browser is opened.
Is there any solution to send a push notification when the browser is closed

Comment: Similar question answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72684047/9997758