# Send A Notification when PWA is Closed

Tags: javascript, angular, notifications, progressive-web-apps

I have made a PWA Todo List App ([Link To App](https://adrish-m.github.io)) using Angular.
I am now planning on adding Notifications which can reach the user when the app is closed.
Since it is a PWA which works offline, I cannot depend on Push Notifications.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the [push and notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Re-engageable_Notifications_Push)

Comment: but push requires server

Comment: Every push is sent by serverside, you don't need to create a custom server but you can use like firebase

Comment: But I am planning to run my app offline

Comment: So you are can't receive the notification. The user will receive only when he will come back online

Comment: But Is there any other way than a Push Notification
Like activating a service worker on a specific time
Or like run the script background
I really don't want to get inside servers and stuff

Comment: You can run a script only if the app is active

Comment: :( 
Such a sad thing

Answer (score 3):

You can make use [of Web Periodic Background Sync API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Periodic_Background_Synchronization_API) You can run this feature offline too and even app is closed, it doesn't require backend server for push as it triggers by the service worker periodically (min 24 hr I guess)

in your project files register sync event:

```
registration.periodicSync.register(constants.periodicBgSyncEventName, {
    minInterval: syncMinInterval,
    networkState: "any",
});
```

in your service worker file listen to the sync and show web notification:

```
self.addEventListener("periodicsync", (event) => {
  if (event.tag === constants.periodicBgSyncEventName) {
    self.registration.showNotification("Wake Time !!!", {
      body: `Hi, Good Morning`,
    });
  }
});
```

Note - In order to use this Periodic Sync API you need to install the PWA first.

Comment: Will it notify you even if the phone is locked? I mean will it trigger a sound or buzzing depending on your phones settings.